# async html5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

For some reason html5 validation message is not shown when I'm using an async request.

Here you can see an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/E4mPG/10/

```
setTimeout(function() {                
  ...
  //this is not working
  target.setCustomValidity('failed!');                
  ...
}, 1000);
```

When checkbox is not checked, everything works as expected,
but when it is checked, the message is not visible.

Can someone explain what should be done?

Comment: Your goal isn't very clear. I've adjusted your code a bit, but I'm sure you mean something else. Can you specify more detailed what you are checked and what the validation function does? http://jsfiddle.net/E4mPG/14/

Comment: When timeout is used, we should see html5 popup message, but it is not shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out that the HTML5 validation messages will only popup when a form submit is in progress.

Here is the process behind my solution (when timeout is checked):

1. Submits the form
2. Sets the `forceValidation` flag
3. Sets the timeout function
4. When the timeout function is called, resubmit the form
5. If the `forceValidation` flag is set, show the validation message

Basically perform two submits, the first one triggered by the button, and the second triggered when the timeout function is called.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/US7h7/3/)

```
var lbl = $("#lbl");
var target = $("#id")[0];

var forceValidation = false;

$("form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$("button").click(function (){                
    var useTimeout = $("#chx").is(":checked");         

    lbl.text("processing...");
    lbl.removeClass("failed");
    target.setCustomValidity('');    
    showValidity();     

    if (forceValidation) {
        forceValidation = false;
        lbl.text("invalid!");
        lbl.addClass("failed");
        target.setCustomValidity('failed!');
        showValidity();
    } else if (useTimeout) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            forceValidation = true;
            $("button").click();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        lbl.text("invalid without timeout!");
        lbl.addClass("failed");
        target.setCustomValidity('failed!');
        showValidity();            
    }
});

function showValidity() {                    
    $("#lbl2").text(target.checkValidity());
};
```

I am running on Chrome version 25.0.1364.172 m.

Answer (score 0):

[`HTMLInputElement.reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/reportValidity), which did not exist at the time this question was first answered, also works for this use case.

```js
function showValidity() {                    
    $("#lbl2").text(target.checkValidity());
    target.reportValidity();
};
```